# span appending multiple time when resizing window

Tags: jquery

I am creating a submenu for mobile and add icon through js it appending again and again  on window resize

```js
function adjustDropdown() {
    var deviceWidth = $(document).width();

    if(deviceWidth <= '991') {
        $('#menu li: has(ul)').addClass('hassub');
        $('#menu')find('.hassub > a').prepand('<span class="dropdown-icon"><i class="rc-icon-angle-down"></i></span>');

        $('.hassub > span').click(function() {
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        }

        );
    }

}

$(function() {
    adjustDropdown();
    var resizeTimer = adjustDropdown;

    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

        //ignore previous trigger
        resizeTimer= setTimeout(function() {
            //wait to execute handler again
            //execute actual handler here
            console.log('Resized finished.');
            adjustDropdown();
        }

        , 150);
    }

    );
}

);
```

when resizing the window it not append multiple times

Comment: It's because the `resize` event fires once *per pixel* that the window is resized by. I'd suggest making the 10ms timeout much longer. Something around 150ms should fix the issue

Comment: sorry I updated wrong code last time. this is right code

Comment: Can you please share HTML Code as well

Comment: Surely you mean [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and not `prepand`

Comment: You should **delete all your javascript** and do this via *CSS*. Your code cannot work and will never perform as fast as *CSS*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use a javascript linter to verify your javascript/jQuery and detect silly mistakes. I don't expect the above code to work at all tbh.

**Your jQuery css-selector should be:** #menu li:has(ul) without the space (and usually the other way around, except you have another ul inside your li.

**The second jQuery line has multiple errors:**
use $().find instead of $()find
its .prepend and not .prepand

And so on...